# Pandas timeseries bins and indexing

Tags: python, pandas

I have some experimental data collected from a number of samples at set time intervals, in a dataframe organised like so:

```
Studynumber    Time    Concentration
1               20         80
1               40         60
1               60         40
2               15         95 
2               44         70
2               65         30
```

Although the time intervals are supposed to be fixed, there is some variation in the data based on when they were actually collected. I want to create bins of the Time column, calculate an 'average' concentration, and then compare the difference between actual concentration and average concentration for each studynumber, at each time.

To do this, I created a column called 'roundtime', then used a groupby to calculate the mean:

```
data['roundtime']=data['Time'].round(decimals=-1)
meanconc = data.groupby('roundtime')['Concentration'].mean()
```

This gives a pandas series of the mean concentrations, with roundtime as the index. Then I want to get this back into the main frame to calculate the difference between each actual concentration and the mean concentration:

```
data['meanconcentration']=meanconc.loc[data['roundtime']].reset_index()['Concentration']
```

This works for the first 60 or so values, but then returns NaN for each entry, I think because the index of data is longer than the index of meanconcentration.

On the one hand, this looks like an indexing issue - equally, it could be that I'm just approaching this the wrong way. So my question is: a) can this method work? and b) is there another/better way of doing it? All advice welcome!

Comment: Are you wanting `data['meanconcentration'] = data.groupby('roundtime')['Concentration'].transform('mean')`? This returns a `Series` with an index aligned to your original df

Comment: Can you put this into an answer, and explain what .transform('mean') does? It doesn't give me NaN - just need to check it gives me the correct values! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) to add a column from a `groupby` aggregation, this will create a `Series` with it's index aligned to the original df so you can assign it back correctly:

```
In [4]:
df['meanconcentration'] = df.groupby('roundtime')['Concentration'].transform('mean')
df

Out[4]:
   Studynumber  Time  Concentration  roundtime  meanconcentration
0            1    20             80         20               87.5
1            1    40             60         40               65.0
2            1    60             40         60               35.0
3            2    15             95         20               87.5
4            2    44             70         40               65.0
5            2    65             30         60               35.0
```